# Windows Authentication with MySQLdb in Python

Tags: python, mysql

Is there a way to connect to MySQL database with Windows Authentication in Python? It is enabled on MySQL server, I login into it with Microsoft MySQL Server Management Studio no problem. However, usual setup:

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="sampleserver\\demo",
                      db="sample")
```

doesnt seem to work. In fact, host is not even recognized. Our DBA didnt give me a endpoint aside from that host. It works for the Management Studio.

**Edit 1**

As per suggestion in the answer, tried connecting with the connection string method with pyodbc library.

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};"
                      "SERVER=server_name\\demo;"
                      "DATABASE=sample;"
                      "UID=auth_windows")
```

Double backslash, I'm escaping the backsalsh in the server name

Getting fairly long error message:

```
Error: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'auth_windows'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); 
[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'auth_windows'. (18456)")
```

When I tried to add `IntegratedSecurity=yes`, I also get:

```
[01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)
```

Comment: if you are trying to use windows auth, why are you passing in username and password?

Comment: this just an example of connection code of this library, frankly.. no idea how to do it

Comment: "MySQL" Server Management Studio? Are you sure this isn't Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: It is, i left out Microsoft part, edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Jaco's answer but pyodbc library requires slightly different string, or it will produce unrecognized attribute error:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;Uid=auth_window;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the connection string you need to use:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;IntegratedSecurity=yes;Uid=auth_windows;
```

This option is available from Connector/NET version 6.4.4, but please note that is requires the Windows Native Authentication Plugin must to be installed.

Comment: Getting an error for using `IntegratedSecurity=yes` and Login failed for user for the auth_windows user. Windows authentication is on, as I login with it using the Management Studio