# Connect to MSSQL in Python2.7.11 (Windows 10 Professional)

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, pymssql

I tried to connect to a remote MSSQL server by using pymssql package but then I get "ImportError: No module named pymssql".

Yes, I have done a **pip install pymssql** which worked. I also looked into installing Cython but it seems such install would give more headaches, so not worth to attempt with such. If I am not totally wrong, pymssql recuires Cython.

The OS I am using is Windows 10 Professional.

Remote connection to MSSQL does work, since at the other side of the office they are connected to the MSSQL server by software Qlik. The MSSQL server firewall does not block port 1433.

So, since pymssql seems not to work out of the box, I have tried to import pyodbc, which in this case gives some error message and does not connect. To this point I tried different solutions listed here on SE and none worked so far.

Following appears so far to be the most successful approach:

```
import pyodbc
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=gxn.database.windows.net;DATABASE=instantcopy;UID=testdb@gxn;PASSWORD=verysecret')
cur = con.cursor()
con.close()
```

The error is:

*pyodbc.Error: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'testdb'.
 (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [01S00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000]
 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'testdb'. (18456); [01S00] [Microsoft][OD
BC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)")*

Any ideas?

Update1:

Using following correction.. I got this line from Azure suggesting following connection string:

Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=xxx-instantorcopy;Uid=xxxtestdb@xxx;Pwd={your_password_here};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;

Solved:

The password was incorrect. So, if anyone is to attempt to connect to mssql I can tell you that I failed with 3 connectors and finally made it with **pyodbc**.

Comment: SQL Server has two authentication methods, "SQL Server" and "Windows". Based on your username it looks like you are trying to use a "Windows" method. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857084/windows-authentication-with-mysqldb-in-python . Note: the question states MySQL but in the comments it is corrested to SQL Server

Comment: ``PASSWORD`` should be ``PWD`` in the connection string

Comment: @Mr.F Thanks, but PWD did not make any difference.

Comment: No, pymssql does not require Cython. Do you by chance have more than one flavour of Python on your machine (e.g. 2.x and 3.x, or 32-bit and 64-bit)?

Comment: @Bryan - If you're referring to *"I have done a pip install pymssql which worked"*, I think they meant that pip didn't barf, not that they were able to actually use pymssql.

Comment: @GordThompson That makes *much* more sense, thanks!

Comment: I use 2.7.11.. to be honest I am a Python n00b from the C++98 and Matlab world. Correct, pip didn't barf... also upgraded pip to latest version.